# React Native: How to create drop down button with onpress functions

Tags: react-native

i'm trying to create an app using React Native. I'm trying to make a drop down option that allow users to click, which will then be directed to another screen within the app.

I have tried using {DropDownItem} from "react-native-drop-down-item", and {Dropdown} from "react-native-material-dropdown", but these two don't seem to made for the function of a clickable contents within the dropdown.

Would appreciate any help with codes, thank you so much!

(I included a picture, hopefully it helps to explain what i'm looking for) [Visual representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtLwE.jpg)

Comment: what exactly do you have currently in terms of code? what navigation package do you use?

Comment: @HagaiHarari I am currently using Navigation Container from "@react-navigation/native" and createStackNavigator from "@react-navigation/stack".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make if/else statement to check the value of the drop down.

```
onChangeText={(value) => {
        this.setState({
          value,
        });
        if (this.state.value === '1') {
          this.props.navigation.navigate('BlogDetails');
        } else if (this.state.value === '2') {
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Blog');
        }
      }}
```

Here a link to expo snack to see the full code:

https://snack.expo.io/@malfuckingfurion/change-screen-from-dropdown

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what i needed!